# Why is spark MEMORY_AND_DISK slower than MEMORY_ONLY?

Tags: apache-spark

I have a pretty typical RDD scenario where I gather some data, persist it, and then use the persisted RDD multiple times for various transforms.  Persisting speeds things up by an order of magnitude, so persisting is definitely warranted.

But I'm surprised at the relative speed of the different methods of persisting. If I persist using `MEMORY_AND_DISK`, each subsequent use of the persisted RDD takes about 10% longer than if I use `MEMORY_ONLY`.  Why is that?  I would have expected them to have the same speed if the data fits in memory, and I expected `MEMORY_AND_DISK` to be faster if some partitions don't fit in memory.  Why do my timings consistently not show that to be true?

Comment: But if the cache is discarded the data needs to be requeried.  Those queries are slow, an order of magnitude slower than writing/reading a cache to/from disk.

Answer (score 0):

Your CPU typically access memory at around 10 Gb/s whereas an access to an SSD takes 600Mb/s
The partitions that don't fit into memory when MEMORY_ONLY is chosen are recomputed using the parent rdds partitionning. If you have no wide dependency that should be ok

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but I don't think this explains what I'm seeing.  The parent RDD queries data directly from a database, and it's very slow.  That's why if I remove the call to persist() it takes 10 times longer than when I persist.  If a partition doesn't fit into memory when using MEMORY_ONLY, wouldn't it have to be recomputed exactly as it does without the call to persist, which is slower than MEMORY_AND_DISK?  And if it does fit into memory, wouldn't MEMORY_AND_DISK be just as fast as MEMORY_ONLY because it doesn't have to go to disk?

Comment: Yes, the disk is used only when there is no more room in your memory so it should be the same.
Maybe it comes for the serialazation process when your data is stored on your disk. Try using the kryo serializer if you can :
conf.set("spark.serializer","org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer")

Comment: I'll give it a shot.

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to tell without the context, but there are at least two cases where `MEMORY_AND_DISK`:

- Data is larger than available memory - with `MEMORY_AND_DISK` partitions that doesn't fit in memory will be stored on disk.
- Partitions have been evicted from memory - with `MEMORY_AND_DISK` there are stored on disk, with `MEMORY_ONLY` there are lost and have to be recomputed and eviction might trigger large GC sweep.

Finally you have to remember that `_DISK` can use different levels of hardware and software caching so different block might be accessed with a speed comparable to the main memory.